# How to get data out of reactive function in Shiny to create new columns on the same DF

Tags: r, shiny

In my script below, Shiny is fetching data from PostgresSQL as a reactive function and I want to manipulate the output of that reactive function (just like we do in a data frame), so that I can then pass it to the renderPlot function to get the output I desire.

I will really appreciate any help in letting me know how to get this working. I have not included error message because I believe error is happening at the handling of the reactive function.

Thanks for the help! Highly appreciated.

```
#server side operation

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(DBI)
library(RPostgreSQL)

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <-dbConnect(drv,dbname = "", host = "valid credentials", port = 5439,
           user = "USER", password = "password")

dates <- seq(as.Date(as.character(Sys.Date() - 33)), as.Date(as.character(Sys.Date() - 1)), by = 1)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session)  {

generate <- function(dates){

listofdfs <- list() #Create a list in which you intend to save your df's. 

for (i in 1:length(dates)){



data <- reactive({dbGetQuery(con, sprintf("select Column A, CAST (date AS date), id from My_Table 
                                       where id =", input$user_id," and
                                       date <= '%s' and date >= '%s'- INTERVAL '7 days'", dates[i], dates[i]))


data$Column_A_mean <- mean(data[,1]) #creating a new column like we do in a data frame (DF)
  })

 listofdfs[[i]] <- data() # save your dataframes into the list
 }

return(listofdfs) #Return the list of dataframes.
}


df <- do.call("rbind", generate(dates))

output$Coolplot <- renderPlot({
ggplot(data = df, aes(date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Column A, colour = "Column A"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Column_A_mean, colour = "Column_A_mean"))
     })

  })
```

Comment: You can not put the reactive in the loop, rather put a loop in the reactive.

Comment: Hi @HubertL...Thanks again for replying....could you please tell me, why do I need to put reactive function inside loop and also, how will I be able to add another column to the df returned from reactive function....Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the `reactive` out of the function, for example you can call the function from the `reactive`:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session)  {

  generate <- function(dates){
    listofdfs <- list() #Create a list in which you intend to save your df's. 
    for (i in 1:length(dates)){
      data <- dbGetQuery(con, sprintf("select Column A, CAST (date AS date), id from My_Table 
                                                where id =", input$user_id," and
                                                date <= '%s' and date >= '%s'- INTERVAL '7 days'", dates[i], dates[i]))
      data$Column_A_mean <- mean(data[,1]) #creating a new column like we do in a data frame (DF)
      listofdfs[[i]] <- data() # save your dataframes into the list
    }
    return(listofdfs) #Return the list of dataframes.
  }

  df <- reactive({do.call("rbind", generate(dates))})

  output$Coolplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = df(), aes(date)) +
      geom_line(aes(y = Column A, colour = "Column A"))+
      geom_line(aes(y = Column_A_mean, colour = "Column_A_mean"))
  })

})
```

Comment: @HubertL...Thanks for your answer and also helping me know, "How to put reactive inside loop". I appreciate your help like last time!...Thank you very much...:)

Comment: @HubertL...I have stuck with one question and will appreciate if you could help..I keep getting error "ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class matrix"....any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Try with `as.data.frame(do.call...` instead

Comment: Thanks...I guess that worked since I am not getting that error anymore but now I get other errors. Even browse() is not helpful at this moment....Thanks again for replying!...highly appreciate you help :)